# Need help with detecting onset of audio in wav file

Tags: filter-design, python, wave, linear-chirp

I'm new to DSP and I'm learning as I go. I have an audio file with a chirp signal(2kHz). I played and recorded this chirp signal and the recording has a lot of environmental sounds.

[Here is my code:](https://repl.it/@NEHANIPHADKAR/ChirpDetection)

Comment: You could feed the signal through a 2kHz high-pass signal and monitor its output. If the output is above some threshold for X amount of time, you can consider the signal to have started.

Comment: You might find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=onset) and [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22matched+filter%22) useful.